# setsid() after fork() can't generate a core dump

Tags: linux, fork, coredump

To run the program,I wrote a shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
ulimit -c unlimited
ulimit -n 65535
/usr/local/bin/myprogram -D #-D here means run in daemon
```

When I run command: kill -3 pid.
It will not generate core dump file.
After I delete "-D" from shell(noted:the program will not  run in daemon),and run command "kill -3 pid",it will generate a core dump.

I guess it may be cause by terminal session id.

How should I do for generate a core dump with running in daemon?

The fork code is:

```
void Daemonize()
{
    pid_t pid, sid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) 
    {
        //Fork error
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        //Child
        char *daemondir;
        umask(027);
        sid = setsid();//it's this cause that can't generate core dump 
        if (sid < 0)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        dosomething();
        ...
    }
    //Parent exits
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

setsid does not mean core dump not generating.

I test you code on my environment kernel 3.10 x86_64. In my environment, it alway generates core dump in current directory.

Check the directory where core dump is generated.

You may need to change [/proc/sys/kernel/]core_pattern to change the dir.